# How to use PyArray_SearchSorted in Numpy C API

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-c-api

In a C extension, I am accessing two arrays passed to the function:

```
PyObject *xw_array = PyArray_FROM_OTF(xw_obj, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_IN_ARRAY);
PyObject *x1_array = PyArray_FROM_OTF(x1_obj, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_IN_ARRAY);
```

and I then want to use `PyArray_SearchSorted` with these two arrays - I am currently doing:

```
PyObject *ix_array = PyArray_SearchSorted(xw_array, x1_array);
```

But this leads to the following error:

```
propagate_pure.c:123:138: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 4, have 2
PyObject *ix_array = (*(PyObject * (*)(PyArrayObject *, PyObject *, NPY_SEARCHSIDE, PyObject *)) PyArray_API[131])(xw_array, x1_array);
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                   ^
```

What is the correct way to use `PyArray_SearchSorted`? What are the four arguments required? The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_SearchSorted) only mentions two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full declaration of `PyArray_SearchSorted` is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.8.x/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L2088):

```
NPY_NO_EXPORT PyObject *
PyArray_SearchSorted(PyArrayObject *op1, PyObject *op2,
                     NPY_SEARCHSIDE side, PyObject *perm)
```

You need to provide a `side` and a `perm` arguments. The defaults being `NPY_SEARCHLEFT` and `NULL`. So the following should work:

```
PyObject *ix_array = PyArray_SearchSorted(xw_array, x1_array,
                                          NPY_SEARCHLEFT, NULL);
```